# Common Lisp - Is there a built-in function to filter a plist by keys?

Tags: common-lisp, plist

I'm looking for a built-in function like the `pfilter-by-keys` below:

```cl
(pfilter-by-keys '(:a :b) '(:c 10 :b 20 :a 4))
;; => (:B 20 :A 4)
```

Its code is pretty simple:

```cl
(defun pfilter-by-keys (keys plist)
  "List -> PList -> PList
  Returns a new plist with only the keys/values correspondent to the given
  keys."
  (loop for (k v) on plist by #'cddr
        when (member k keys :test #'equal)
          append (list k v)))
```

Does CL has some built-in function like the one above?

PS.: [Alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html#Conses) has a very close function: `remove-from-plist`.

Comment: In your function you should probably be testing by `eq` or `eql` rather than `equal` if your keys are going to be symbols. Or at least have a `:test` parameter which defaults to `eql`. You can also change your `append` to `nconc` as the list is fresh or even change it to `collect k and collect v` as these will probably perform better. Ultimately if you want to do these map-like-things with plists you should probably consider using hashmaps (which can be faster) or alists (for which the normal list operators are more applicable) instead.

Comment: I thought `equal` falls back to `eq` when comparing symbols ([ref](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equal.htm#equal)).

Comment: It does but to compare two things with `eq` compiles to one instruction whereas testing with `equal` can be almost as fast as `eq` for things that are `eq` but much slower for things that are not (having to dispatch on type and potentially recurse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no function to do this (and this isn’t the sort of thing one usually wants to do)

There is a macro `remf` which removes a key from a plist in some place.

Another way you might achieve this is by:

```
(destructuring-bind (&key (a nil ap) (b nil bp) &allow-other-keys) plist
  (append (if ap (list :a a)) (if bp (list :b b))))
```

But note that this only works if you already know what keys you want to keep and this does not preserve the order in the plist and it does not preserve repeated keys (i.e. if your plist contains the key `:a` multiple times the result will contain it only once).

You can modify this for non keyword keys using the normal lambda list syntax for general (symbol) keys.

Comment: Thanks @dan-robertson! My case is very simple and I didn't thought about about applying `destructuring-bind`. Good idea!

Answer (score 5):

[`CL:GET-PROPERTIES`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get_pr.htm#get-properties) is a building block:

```
(defun keep-properties (plist indicator-list &aux k v)
  "Keeps all property list entries for a given indicator-list."
  (loop do (setf (values k v plist)
                 (get-properties plist indicator-list))
        while plist
        collect k collect v
        do (pop plist) (pop plist)))
```

Note, that it is better to collect twice, than to append/list in a `LOOP`.

Comment: Thanks @rainer-joswig! Good to know about `get-properties` and the syntax to collect twice.